# Roslyn with .net 4.5.2

Tags: .net-4.5, roslyn

Has anyone successfully installed Roslyn nuget packages on projects with target framework 4.5.2?

I am trying to install Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting package, but havent seen success yet. It fails due to various dependent assemblies.

Please let me know if you have installed any Roslyn build on framework > 4.5

Answer (score 8):

I took a look into [Cake build system project](https://github.com/cake-build/cake/blob/823333b113a46f219655f2ecfd6fc789b147f624/src/Cake/Cake.csproj), they use C# scripting and whole thing runs on .Net 4.5. The secret behind this is:

```
<package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.CSharp" version="1.0.0-rc2" targetFramework="net45" />
```

I guess rc2 was compiled against .Net 4.5 so it should work.

Example `packages.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" version="1.0.0-rc2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common" version="1.0.0-rc2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" version="1.0.0-rc2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.Common" version="1.0.0-rc2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.CSharp" version="1.0.0-rc2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Immutable" version="1.1.33-beta" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Metadata" version="1.0.18-beta" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Or using the Package Management Console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp -Version 1.0.0-rc2 -IncludePrerelease
Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.CSharp -Version 1.0.0-rc2 -IncludePrerelease
```

Comment: Can confirmed that now. I made simple test application that targerts .Net 4.5 and I was able to make C# scripting work.

Comment: One more thing - you may need to amend assembly binding redirect in app.config: `<dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Collections.Immutable" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.1.0" newVersion="1.1.33.0"/></dependentAssembly>`

Answer (score 4):

Scripting requires fixes made as part of .Net 4.6.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting latest version 1.2.1 (and previous versions) does not support library of 4.5. It requires at least .net 4.6.

Comment: Version 1.0.0-rc2 will work on .Net 4.5. I made simple test project yesterday and everything works.